# Error in PubNub Angularjs, channel group

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I've followed this [DOCUMENT](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angularjs-javascript/stream-controller) to working with PubNub Angularjs, channel group. But I got this error:

[image]

Here's my code:

```js
Pubnub.init({
  publish_key: constants.PUBNUB_PUBLISH_KEY,
  subscribe_key: constants.PUBNUB_SUBSCRIBE_KEY,
  uuid: $scope.user.IncubatorContactId + "_Layout",
  error: function(error) {
    console.log('Pubnub.init() Error:', error);
  }
});

Pubnub.channel_group_add_channel({
  callback: function(m) {
    console.log('channel_group_add_channel', 'success', m);
  },
  channel: channels[0],
  channel_group: $scope.user.IncubatorContactId
});
```

Someone please help me!

Comment: What is your channel group name? What is your channel name? Can you provide the complete code example to support@pubnub.com (along with you keys) so they can reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, channel_group should be string instead of number:

```js
channel_group: "" + $scope.user.IncubatorContactId + ""
```

Comment: I suspected it was something about the name of channel or channel group. Thanks for posting your root cause/solution.